# .NET Upgrade Assistant upgrading a library built with .NET Framework 4.6.1 to netstandard2.0

Tags: .net-6.0, .net-standard, .net-framework-version

I have a `.NET Framework 4.6.1` project. I'm following instructions on this [.NET Upgrade Assistant Page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant/tutorial/intro) to upgrade to `.NET 6.0`. After I completed the upgrade, I looked at the project file. The Upgrade tool upgraded the **v4.6.1** to **netstandard2.0**.

Shouldn't the project be upgraded to **.NET 6.0** and not **netstandard2.0**? Is it not possible to upgrade to **.NET 6.0** from **.NET Framework 4.6.1**.

`<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>`

to

`<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`

Answer (score 0):

You can find some solution on this link:

[Migrate from .net standard to .net 6 using the upgrade tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72883014/migrate-from-net-standard-to-net-6-using-the-upgrade-tool)

Already answered.

But based on my understanding. If you update a class library then the assist tool will change your project to netstandard.

After that I think you are able to change it via the csproj to .net6.